# (Z3Py) Concat, quantifiers and bit-vectors

Tags: python, z3, bitvector

Is it possible to make use of quantifiers with bit-vectors and concatenations? To illustrate, running the following code in the newest Z3:

```
a = BitVec('a', 8)
b = Concat(BitVec('b', 4), BitVec('c', 4))

prove(ForAll(a, Exists(b, a == b)))
```

produces the following error:

```
BitVecRef instance has no attribute '__len__'
```

I have tried adding a simple `__len__` method in `BitVecRef` but further problems arose.

Without the `Concat`, the code works as expected. For example:

```
a = BitVec('a', 8)
b = BitVec('b', 8)

prove(ForAll(a, Exists(b, a == b)))
```

outputs the correct: `proved`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example defines the value b as shorthand for a concatenation.
It gets passed as the bound variable to the quantifier Exists(b, a == b).
Quantifiers expect a list of basic constants, such as a, b, c below, but not compound
expressions, such as d. Below is a version of your puzzle that gets processed:

```
a = BitVec('a', 8)
b = BitVec('b', 4)
c = BitVec('c', 4)
d = Concat(b, c)

prove(ForAll(a, Exists(b, a == d)))
```

Comment: I see. So quantifiers and compound expressions are a no-go. Thanks Nikolaj!